# how to create tab bar controller in a view controller not in app delegate? IOS 4.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a tab bar application, but i want to create tab bar controller not in Main.xib by using interface builder. Because my app has no Main.Xib. So I either should do it in ViewController.xib or programmatically in a controller/appdelegate. I couldnt find any good tutorial or example for it.

In my app i have

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
ViewController.h
ViewController.m
ViewController.xib
```

My application starts with view of ViewController.xib know i want to add not a tab bar but a tab bar controller which will always stay bottom of views. How can i do that?

appdelagete.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I have tried to do it programatically by looking at [apple developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html) but couldnt figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any example code

Comment: u wnat to load tabbar controller in ViewController by click of buton or what do u want?

Comment: by default, when application did finish launch it should stay there like a regular tab bar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this working great
appdelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *rootController
```

appdelegate.m

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.rootController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a tab bar with 3 views

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: `self.rootController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ViewController *view1=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    
    self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1 nil];` gives error "called object type``ViewController" is not a funtion or a function pointer

Comment: What is ViewController? Did you custom create this?

Comment: yes, when you apply your code xcode wants a definitio for view1, vie2 etc. I looked appledeveloper doc, view1 should be define with target viewcotnroller.

Comment: I think you better have a look at the sample code provided by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

///AppDelegate.m file : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
//initiate window
window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

//initiate viewcontrollers
FirstViewController *aFirstViewController = [FirstViewController new];

SecondViewController *aSecondViewController = [SecondViewController new];

 aFirstViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"First";
aFirstViewController.tabBarIte
 aSecondViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";

gTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
gTabBarController.viewControllers = @[aFirstViewController ,aSecondViewController];

//show the main window and also make it key
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


window.rootViewController = gTabBarController;
```